# added fields are not working in edit or create mode in backpack cms

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

In Backpack CMS framework I have created a table using migration fields like : 'parent_id' and 'is_active'.
I have added these fields in the crud controller using the following command:

```
$this->crud->addFields(array(

            ['name' => 'title',
            'label' => 'Title',
            'type'=>'text'],

            ['name' => 'parent_id',
            'label' => 'Parent ID',
            'type'=> 'number'],

            ['name' => 'is_active',
            'label' => 'Is Active',
            'type'=>'number']

        ), 'update/create/both');
```

It should work in edit mode and create mode like my other tables. It shows the defined fields in the create and update form but unfortunately they doesn't work and always return the default value or previous value in the record.
I've tried adding the field in single format but there was no use.

Comment: please add your implementation, your logic

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that it is in backpack cms

Comment: then follow their input format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the fillable variable..... Only the 'title' field was in the fillable variable of the related model.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here: `'update/create/both'` you should pick only one of the three options.

What you want is to use only `both`. But since it is the default value, you don't really need to add it to the end of the `addFields` function.

This will work:

```
$this->crud->addFields([[  
        'name' => 'title',
        'label' => 'Title',
        'type' => 'text'
    ], [
        'name' => 'parent_id',
        'label' => 'Parent ID',
        'type' => 'number'
    ], [
        'name' => 'is_active',
        'label' => 'Is Active',
        'type' => 'number'
    ]
]);
```

Comment: I just tested your solution and unfortunately it didn't work...... Fortunately I've found the problem and it is because of the fillable fields.... I had just added the 'title' field to the fillable variable... Because of the default values of the fields they didn't give me any error